# Which SDK exactly to install to use WinHTTP in Visual Studio 2003, XP 2003, SP3?

Tags: visual-c++, sdk, proxy, winhttp

My OS is XP 2003, SP 3. We have MS VC++ code (not .NET), in Visual Studio 2003. (This is not the time for us to upgrade to a later Visual Studio version.) I want to use WinHTTP API's (winhttp.h) in my code. What SDK exactly do I need to install? What version? Where to get it?

Anything shown in the following website seem to be too new and will not work with my environment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx

I am afraid that any "wrong" installations may ruin my environment and it would cause us more time to recover.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WinHTTP 5.1 [is available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in clean Windows XP SP3, so no redistributables are required to be installed in such system.

For development you need to install Windows SDK which is compatible with your version of Visual Studio. [Microsoft ® Windows Server® 2003 R2 Platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22668) announces that its samples are tested with VS 2003, so seems to be compatible, or you might want to look for a more recent. SDK will get you `winhttp.lib` and `winhttp.h`.

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK#Versions) that next version of Windows SDK is already incompatible with Visual Studio .NET 2003.